# How to Find the difference in two JSON Files and printing the line number where the difference has occured

Tags: java, json, gson, compare

I have two JSON files with the order of object being same. I want to print the difference in both of them and also print the line number where the difference has occurred.
For Example.
The output should be like:

"Difference found in Expected.json:
 on "Print LineNumber here" -->  print Difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File(file1Path));
Scanner file2 = new Scanner(new File(file2Path));

int lineCounter = 1;
while(file1.hasNextLine() && file2.hasNextLine()) {
    lineFile1 = file1.nextLine();   
    lineFile2 = file2.nextLine(); 

    if(!lineFile1.equals(lineFile2)) {
        System.out.println("Difference found in Expected.json: on " + lineCounter);
        System.out.println("File1 line: " + lineFile1);
        System.out.println("File2 line: " + lineFile2);
    }
    lineCounter++;
}
```